# Gatsby related contents

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm making a site with Gatsby.
I've several Mdx pages. Some of these pages are "related" each other (by *slug*).
For example:

```
pageone.mdx
   -- frontmatter --
   image: "team.jpg"

pagetwo.mdx
   -- frontmatter --
   image: "second.jpg"
   relateds:
    - pagetwo
```

An extract of my gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({  
    stage,
    rules,
    loaders,
    plugins,
    actions, }) => {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
            module: {

            },
            plugins: [
              plugins.define({
                __DEVELOPMENT__: stage === `develop` || stage === `develop-html`,
              }),
            ],
            node: {
              fs: "empty",
            },
          })
  }

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    const image = node.frontmatter.image

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: value,
    })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `image`,
      value: image,
    })

  }
}
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions , reporter}) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
              image
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
  }

  const pages = result.data.allMdx.edges

  pages.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/mdTemplate.js`),
      context: { id: node.id, 
                 image: node.fields.image },
      })
  })
}


exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type Mdx implements Node {
      image: String,
      relateds: [Mdx] @link(by: "slug", from: "relateds")
    }

  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

My aim is to obtain for each node a "related contents" of him.

White the code above I've a "relateds" field for each mdx node but If I explore with graphql client I obtain : *null*

Answer (score 1):

Solved using a "resolver":

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  const resolvers = {
      Mdx: {
        // To transform the Frontmatter relateds to Mdx nodes
        relateds: {
        resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
          const relpages = ('relateds' in source.frontmatter) ? context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            type: `Mdx`,
            query: {
              filter : {
                slug: {
                  in: source.frontmatter.relateds
                }
              }
            }

          }) : []
          return relpages
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```